# Window's close, minimize, maximize buttons don't work while menu is popped up

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm developing a WPF desktop application on .net core 3.1 and it has a classic menu bar with menu items.

The small problem I found is that while the menu item pops up, title bar buttons can't be clicked directly. For example, if I clicked close(x) button, only the pop up menu is hidden, but no window_Closing event is fired. I have to click twice to actually close the window.

My concern is that regular window's application's behavior is different and these window's buttons are directly working even if menu is popped up. **Note that application with menu bar such as visual studio 2019, visual studio code all don't have this problem and title bar buttons are working even if menu item is popped up.**

Even though it might be just a trivial issue, this inconsistency might be confusing for some users and this makes my WPF app look non native and awkward.

Here is a snippet from my XAML code and window close event handler in my MainWindow code behind.

```xml
<Window x:Class="MyApp.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        Title="{Binding Title}" Height="1000" Width="1600" 
        Icon="{StaticResource AppIcon}"
        Closing="Window_Closing">
...
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Menu>
                <MenuItem Header="File">

                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding New}"/>
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding Open}"/>
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding Save}"/>
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding SaveAs}"/>
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding SaveAll]"/>

                    <Separator />

                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding Exit}" />
                </MenuItem>
```

```
        private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                if (DataContext is MainWindowViewModel vm)
                    vm.Exit();
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
```

Am I coding wrongly and is there a way to fix this behavior? Or is this just a normal behavior of all WPF applications? It seems even a simplest sample applications from WPF books show the same behavior.

**EDIT:**
I suspect that the real issue is something to do with the fact that WPF pop ups are rendered higher than Win32 elements. I'm wondering if there is an easy way  to change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think that behavior is the default and there is no easy way to implement the behavior you want.

One way to implement it is to handle the MenuItem.SubmenuClosed event and detect the UIElement that was clicked (by hit testing) and react accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this is no longer a problem if I replace normal WPF Window with MetroWindow using [MahApp.Metro](https://mahapps.com/) framework. With MahApp's MetroWindow, every buttons on the window title bar can be clicked directly even when menu is opened.

It seems that MetroWindow is rendering its title bar and buttons using control template and it isn't real Win32 windows's title bar.

```xml
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MahApps.Templates.MetroWindow" TargetType="{x:Type mah:MetroWindow}">
            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  LayoutTransform="{Binding LayoutTransform, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                  RenderTransform="{Binding RenderTransform, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                  UseLayoutRounding="True">
                <AdornerDecorator>
                    <Grid UseLayoutRounding="False">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=BorderThickness, Converter={StaticResource ThicknessToDoubleConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static converters:ThicknessSideType.Left}}" />
                            <!--  icon  -->
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <!--  left window commands, title, right window commands  -->
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <!--  min,max,close buttons  -->
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=BorderThickness, Converter={StaticResource ThicknessToDoubleConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static converters:ThicknessSideType.Right}}" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=BorderThickness, Converter={StaticResource ThicknessToDoubleConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static converters:ThicknessSideType.Top}}" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_WindowTitleBackground"
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                   Fill="{TemplateBinding WindowTitleBrush}"
                                   Focusable="False"
                                   StrokeThickness="0" />
    
                        <!--  icon  -->
                        <ContentControl x:Name="PART_Icon"
                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Height="{Binding TitleBarHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        MinWidth="{Binding TitleBarHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                        Panel.ZIndex="1"
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding IconTemplate}"
                                        Focusable="False"
                                        Visibility="{TemplateBinding ShowIconOnTitleBar, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    
                        <mah:MetroThumb x:Name="PART_WindowTitleThumb"
                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                                        Style="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.Thumb.WindowTitle}"
                                        UseLayoutRounding="True" />
    
                        <DockPanel Grid.Row="1"
                                   Grid.Column="2"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   Focusable="False">
                            <!--  the left window commands  -->
                            <mah:ContentPresenterEx x:Name="PART_LeftWindowCommands"
                                                    Height="{Binding TitleBarHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                    controlzEx:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"
                                                    Content="{Binding LeftWindowCommands, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                    DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                                    Focusable="False" />
                            <!--  the right window commands  -->
                            <mah:ContentPresenterEx x:Name="PART_RightWindowCommands"
                                                    Height="{Binding TitleBarHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                    controlzEx:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"
                                                    Content="{Binding RightWindowCommands, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                                    Focusable="False" />
                            <!--  the title bar  -->
                            <mah:MetroThumbContentControl x:Name="PART_TitleBar"
                                                          Height="{Binding TitleBarHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding TitleAlignment}"
                                                          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                                          VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                                                          ContentCharacterCasing="{TemplateBinding TitleCharacterCasing}"
                                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}"
                                                          Focusable="False">
                                <ContentControl.Foreground>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{x:Static converters:BackgroundToForegroundConverter.Instance}">
                                        <Binding ElementName="PART_WindowTitleBackground"
                                                 Mode="OneWay"
                                                 Path="Fill" />
                                        <Binding Mode="OneWay"
                                                 Path="TitleForeground"
                                                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </ContentControl.Foreground>
                            </mah:MetroThumbContentControl>
                        </DockPanel>
    
                        <!--  the window button commands  -->
                        <mah:ContentPresenterEx x:Name="PART_WindowButtonCommands"
                                                Grid.Row="1"
                                                Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                                Grid.Column="3"
                                                Height="{Binding TitleBarHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                Panel.ZIndex="1"
                                                controlzEx:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"
                                                Content="{Binding WindowButtonCommands, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                Focusable="False" />
    
                        <!--  the main window content  -->
                        <mah:MetroContentControl x:Name="PART_Content"
                                                 Grid.Row="2"
                                                 Grid.Column="0"
                                                 Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                                                 FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
                                                 IsTabStop="False"
                                                 OnlyLoadTransition="True"
                                                 TransitionsEnabled="{TemplateBinding WindowTransitionsEnabled}"
                                                 UseLayoutRounding="True">
                            <mah:ContentPresenterEx x:Name="PART_ContentPresenter"
                                                    Margin="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=BorderThickness, Converter={StaticResource ThicknessBindingConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static converters:ThicknessSideType.Top}}"
                                                    controlzEx:WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"
                                                    UseLayoutRounding="False" />
                        </mah:MetroContentControl>
    
                        <!--  disables the main content when a modal flyout is shown  -->
                        <Rectangle Name="PART_FlyoutModal"
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                   Fill="{TemplateBinding FlyoutOverlayBrush}"
                                   Visibility="Hidden" />
                        <mah:MetroThumb x:Name="PART_FlyoutModalDragMoveThumb"
                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                                        Style="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.Thumb.WindowTitle}"
                                        Visibility="{Binding ElementName=PART_FlyoutModal, Path=Visibility, Mode=OneWay}" />
    
                        <!--  flyouts  -->
                        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
                                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        Panel.ZIndex="2"
                                        Content="{Binding Flyouts, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Focusable="False"
                                        KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None" />
    
                        <!--  inactive dialog container  -->
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_MetroInactiveDialogsContainer"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                              Grid.RowSpan="2"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                              Panel.ZIndex="3"
                              FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" />
    
                        <!--  overlay effect container  -->
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_OverlayBox"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                              Grid.RowSpan="2"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                              Panel.ZIndex="4"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding OverlayBrush}"
                              FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
                              Focusable="False"
                              Opacity="0"
                              Visibility="Hidden" />
    
                        <!--  active dialog container  -->
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_MetroActiveDialogContainer"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                              Grid.RowSpan="2"
                              Grid.Column="1"
                              Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                              Panel.ZIndex="5"
                              FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" />
                    </Grid>
                </AdornerDecorator>
    
                <Border x:Name="PART_Border"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Background="{x:Null}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding GlowBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        UseLayoutRounding="True" />
                <ResizeGrip x:Name="WindowResizeGrip"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            IsTabStop="False"
                            UseLayoutRounding="True"
                            Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </Grid>
```